# how to update value by 1 if username already exist in database using Linq and entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using below code to update login name. But it will append 1 only. But what about if that user name also exists?

```
  string loginname=txtusername.Text;
  var userRec = Context.Repoj.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.LoginName == loginname);
  if(userRec != null)
  {
     loginname = loginname + "1";
  }
```

Comment: "but what about if that user name also exists" - What do you want to happen? Should any trailing number be incremented by 1?

Comment: like txtusername.Text value is ankit and ankit is already exists in database  so my current code will generate loginname= ankit1. but i want if ankit1 also exists in database then it will be ankit2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check it several times in a loop:

```
string originalLogin = txtusername.Text;
string loginname = originalLogin;
int counter = 1;
var userRec = Context.Repoj.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.LoginName == loginname);
while(userRec != null)
{
     loginname = originalLogin + counter;
     counter++;
     userRec = Context.Repoj.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.LoginName == loginname);
}
```

Note: If there are a huge amount of users "ankit1", "ankit2", "ankit3", and so on, the loop might run a long time, maybe even until infinity. You could check if `counter` equals a certain value (extrem case: `int.MaxValue`) and throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks. that while loop is what I am looking for.